# Tokenising column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got an orders table which contains order details delimited by spaces - the order details may contain multiple items (Yes I know this breaks database convention but it's one of our third party databases). I've been able to extract it but the solution isn't very elegant. Not sure if you guys have any better solutions?

Example:
Details column
[Type of order] [quantity] [item] [other information] [Type of order] [quantity] [item] [other information] ...

So each column may contain multiple order items

Comment: Not clear to me.  Can you post 2 or 3 rows of sample data?

Comment: Hard to tell if we have a better solution without you sharing yours.  Honestly, I'd get a new third party provider ^^

Comment: So one row may be like this
Buy 1 AAA Oct 2008 Sell 1 AAA Nov 2008 Buy 3 JJJ Jan 2009

Comment: In this example, I want to extract just the Quantity and Item. I've done basically a nested cursor. I don't have time to post the solution as I'll need to strip out certain things (work privacy) but I'll try to get to it later.

Comment: There's a bazillion examples of string splitting functions out there.

Comment: Is this an EDI document stuffed in a field?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by modifying one of the existing string-splitter functions so that it return not only words, but also their numbers within the original string. Then you have to seek for words 'Buy' and 'Sell', get their numbers, the next two words are the quantity and the item respectively.

**Query**:

```
declare @str varchar(1000)
set @str = 'Buy 1 AAA Oct 2008 Sell 1 AAA Nov 2008 Buy 3 JJJ Jan 2009'

;with words as (
    select word, wordNum
    from ftStringSplit(@str, ' ')
),
tokenNums as (
    select wordNum + 1 as wnQty, wordNum+2 wnItem
    from words
    where word in ('Buy', 'Sell')
)
select wI.word as Item, wQ.word as Qty
from tokenNums tn
    join words wI on wI.wordNum = tn.wnItem
    join words wQ on wQ.wordNum = tn.wnQty
```

**Output**:

```
| ITEM | QTY |
|------|-----|
|  AAA |   1 |
|  AAA |   1 |
|  JJJ |   3 |
```

See <kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/daa96/1)</kbd> sample